# Getting functionName and executionId inside running Firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

Our product is heavily based on Node.js v10 firebase functions, and up until now, we have been using the firebase functions logger SDK for logging purposes. Nevertheless, it is not enough for us anymore as we need to send some additional properties with each log for better filtering in GCP Logging Explorer.

Unfortunately, the very helpful `functionName` and `executionId` labels are not attached to the logs triggered by the Cloud Logging SDK. Are these labels exposed somehow by the Node.js Firebase SDK in order for me to attach them manually to the metadata?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

We have the exact same stack at work and we just create a logger that sits on top of the firebase logger and do basically manual logging.

```
// Use the firebase functions logger to report all logs from out logger to
// Can do logger.info, .error, .log, .warn
// Logger is a custom function function that sits on top of console or firebase logger
// This means initialise a logger singleton using the firebase functions logger as a base
logger(functions.logger)
```

E.g. a typical function log would be:

```
// Use the logger global singleton initialised above
logger.log(`[endpoint-name.methodName] - Execution failed with error code ${error.code} and message ${error.message}`)
```

We just then use the function log search field to find an instance of a particular error. We also report all internal errors to sentry and use that too debug.

Hope this gives you some ideas?

Comment: Although this is a solution, it is kind of hacky and I prefer to avoid it. In addition, how do you get the endpoint and method names?

Comment: We have a custom middleware that adds our endpoint name to our request object before it hits the endpoint. `[${req.endpointName} - ManuallyAddFuncName] - blob`. I also dont think its hacky its a good workable solution.

Comment: It is a good workable solution :) I just prefer to use the logger mechanism for the functionName and the executionId as these labels are very helpful in the explorer. By the way, I did use your idea for taking the data from the request, but I pass them in the log entry metadata instead. This way the labels are shown in the GCP Logging Explorer.

Comment: Ah thats a good idea - glad you figured something out!